# Available space for Chromebook

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app, chromium, chromebook

We are using the below snippet from https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage to get the available space on chromebook device.
We are using "unlimitedStorage" in manifest file.
But on ChrmeBook this is giving us the available space for the entire device and not for the current user profile, what we need is an API/Code which gives us similar results to chrome://quota-internals/

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
    console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
}, 
function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
```

);

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_storage#method-getInfo

Comment: On windows machine we are getting the response as an array of length one but on ChromeBook we are getting an empty array.

Comment: Try this app, see if it gets the correct info: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cog-system-info-viewer/difcjdggkffcfgcfconafogflmmaadco

Comment: Even this application is showing wrong data if we have multiple profiles on ChromeBook